# Complete bipartite graph from 2 to m points

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

How can I show that $K_{2,m}$ is planar for all m?  I can't even seem to draw $K_{2,2}$ without intersection and if I draw it as a square then it seems to fail to be bipartite as the second set lies above and below the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important fact**: You don't need to draw bipartite graphs with all points in one set "near" each other in any sense. Mathematically, the graph is just determined by the set of vertices and the information about which are joined by lines. Whether or not it's bipartite is unaffected by how we draw it. All that matters is that it can be divided into two sets of vertices (which may be separated in space), neither of which has any internal edges.

**Hint**: Put the $m$ points in a straight line. Where can you put the two points to make it easy to draw all the lines without intersection?

Comment: So a graph being bipartite means that we can manoeuvre the vertices such that one set of vertices has a complete mapping to the other but one not yet manoeuvred into this form is implicitly bipartite? And so rearranging the vertices doesn't change its ability to be manoeuvred into such a setting, I think I understand

Comment: Firstly, "a graph being bipartite means that we can manoeuvre the vertices such that one set of vertices has a complete mapping to the other" -- bipartite doesn't require any sort of completeness at all. It's just the requirement that it is possible to colour some vertices red, and the rest blue, such that there are no red-red or blue-blue lines. Secondly, "one not yet manoeuvred into this form is implicitly bipartite [...] rearranging the vertices doesn't change its ability to be manoeuvred into such a setting" You should just say it **is bipartite**; but yes, moving vertices is irrelevant :)

Answer (score 2):

Draw $m$ points in a line, one above and one below.